# Open a PDF with arguments (Page/Named Destination) WITHOUT referencing a specific program

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, pdf

thanks for taking the time to read my quandary.

I need to open a PDF (C# 4.0, winforms).  Now normally this is pretty easy if you aren't passing in arguments (Process.Start to the PDF), but I need to be able to pass in arguments (go to a specific page or named destination right now, maybe more later).

Now I know if you call AcroRd32 you can pass in the arguments needed to do this, but it is possible that the user won't have Acrobat Reader installed on their machine, so I don't really want to call that exe necessarily.  Anyone know of a way to pull this off?

Am I missing an obvious way to do this using something else?

Thanks for your help!

PS - replies can be in C# or VB, don't care

Comment: Is it possible for them to open it in your app? If that's the case you can add the control and do it that way.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include this is winforms

Comment: Mr CoDeXeR, there is not one single file.  The app loads a bunch of different templates that might have help files (PDFs) in them, so I can't include the PDF in the exe.  I don't know of another way to open it in the app

Comment: Did you consider using some open source library to render you pdf in your windows forms application? Something like: http://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com

Comment: If I have to I could go with something like ghostscript, but I'd rather use whatever the normal PDF viewer installed on the system is.

Answer (score 0):

To pass the arguments in `Process.Start()`, you need to call AcroRd32.exe or Acrobat.exe, like:

```
Process myProcess = new Process();    
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "acroRd32.exe"; //not the full application path
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/A \"page=2=OpenActions\" /n C:\\sample.pdf";
myProcess.Start();
```

I suggest putting this is a Try/Catch block, and if it fails then try "Acrobat.exe" as the FileName in another, nested Try/Catch block, and if that fails, default to:

```
Process.Start("C:\\sample.pdf");
```

which doesn't allow you to open to the specific page, but at least the PDF will open if the first two approaches have failed.